# Telethon: how to get invite link to private channel?

Tags: python, telethon

In 1.5 version I did so:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import ExportInviteRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannel, InputPeerChannel
ChannelLink = Client(ExportInviteRequest(
    InputPeerChannel(channel_id=ChannelID,
        access_hash=ChannelHash))).link
```

But it doesn't work now:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ExportInviteRequest'
```

How to do it now?

Answer (score 5):

Raw API is subject to change between minor versions of the library, so the function you're trying to access no longer exists where it used to be.

Whenever this happens, you can [search for the method again](https://tl.telethon.dev?q=export%20invite) to find out where [the new one is](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/export_chat_invite.html):

```py
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ExportChatInviteRequest
```

Usage is still the same:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client(functions.messages.ExportChatInviteRequest(
        ChannelID
    ))
```

You also don't need to construct the `InputPeer` yourself, it's done automatically.